# Test Windows Forms logic with NUnit

Tags: c#, winforms, unit-testing, nunit

I'm diving into unit testing and I would like to know if it is possible to test some special functionality of a dialog or a form with [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org). I have tried [NUnitForms](http://nunitforms.sourceforge.net/), but it lacks good documentation and seems that nobody is mantaining that project. Is it true?

If you have any experience testing Windows Forms, please point me in the right way. Any comments or information are appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: As written by Colin, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/532994/ui-testing-framework-continuous-integration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am having the same problem with NUnitForms. I can launch a form and click a button, but I can't figure out how to get dialogs working, and I can't find much about it at all.
I think this blog was the most useful:
http://blogs.msdn.com/john_daddamio/archive/2006/11/06/getting-started-with-nunitforms.aspx

I had to remap the NUnitForms assembly in my app.config to get it to work with the latest version like this:

```
<configuration>
   <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"> 
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="nunit.framework"
          publicKeyToken="96d09a1eb7f44a77"
          culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.2.7.0" newVersion="2.5.2.9222" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

( http://duncanjasmith.blogspot.com/2007/08/using-nunitforms-with-nunit-framework.html )

I'm hoping this thread will help me, but I might still try project white ( http://www.codeplex.com/white ).

Comment: The project White looks promising. The thing is that I would like to test GUI logic within my Continuous Integration server, so I don't have to bother running the tests on every revision.

Comment: Have you seen this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/532994/ui-testing-framework-continuous-integration

Answer (score 3):

Automated GUI testing tends to be very brittle, and I would guess that this is why NUnitForms isn't being maintained (if that is true).

Spare yourself the agony and look at applying design patterns such as [Model View Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) or [Model View ViewModel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel). This will allow you to unit test the UI logic in a much more robust manner.

Comment: Good advice but there are no mainstream MVC libs/templates for WinForms (afaik).

Comment: @Henk Holterman: Yes and no: there's the super-complex Composite UI Application Block (CAB) from p&p. It's not being maintained either, but you could almost say that about Windows Forms itself as well :)

Comment: The logic I want to test in a form is input validation logic... I think that's still reasonable even using the MVC pattern.

Comment: Yes, but you can still implement input validation logic in an underlying Model instead of directly in your Windows Forms code.

Comment: Never heard of Model View ViewModel for Winforms (I thought it was introduced with WPF). SCSF (a GUI layer on top of CAB), if somewhat complex, provides a nice Model View Presenter framework, and is quite unit testable.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a lot of success using the UI Automation framework that comes as part of .Net 3.0 and later. I've written a [tutorial](http://blog.functionalfun.net/2009/06/introduction-to-ui-automation-with.html) that might help get you started.

Answer (score 0):

There's a very good and easy to understand example of a MVC framework produced by Ayende, see [this entry](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/12/19/effectus-building-ui-based-on-conventions.aspx) on his blog for more details. It's a works by adding a very light-weight infastructure to your application that wires up buttons to events automatically for you.

By using this type of framework you are forced to not have any logic in your View, only in your Presenter. Then you can easily unit test the logic without touching WinForms.

I've started a port of Effectus to .NET 2.0 and WinForms, it's [here](http://github.com/mattwarren/Effectus-in-Winforms) if your interested.

Comment: Hey, your las link goes to a page that says not found! :-O

Comment: Yeah I think github was broken earlier on, but it should be working now.